# Monitor the application logs and pull the error count

Tags: unix, logging, grep

I am very new to Unix command and would like to know the script for doing below things.

1. Need to read the application logs and pull all the errors for last half an hour.
2. Get the unique count of each error.
3. Mail the error count to team.

Steps taken:
I have read the file using grep for keyword error and written to separate file.
Gave permission to file.

Appreciate your help.

Code Snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd Service/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/logs
for file in catalina.out; do
grep "ERROR" $file >error.txt
done
chmod 0777 error.txt
```

**Sample Logs**

```
2014-09-03 16:45:36,814 ERROR xxxService: Could not find tool with id 365 intable:
2014-09-03 16:45:56,444 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 1, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:45:56,444 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 2, mapParams 
2014-09-03 16:45:56,445 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 3, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:45:56,445 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 4, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:45:56,445 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 5, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:46:00,077 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 1, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:46:00,078 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 2, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:46:00,078 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 3, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:46:00,078 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 4, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:46:00,079 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 5, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:46:05,415 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 1, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:46:05,416 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 2, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:46:05,416 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 3, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:46:05,416 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 4, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:46:05,417 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 5, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:46:59,881 ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 5, mapParams
2014-09-03 16:47:03,109 ERROR ErrorManager: 1409780823108: A General Exception Occurred
    null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

Error Message   Count
ERROR xxxService: Could not find tool with id 365 intable:  1
ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 1, mapParams  3
ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 2, mapParams  3
ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 3, mapParams  3
ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 4, mapParams  3
ERROR yyyService: summary counts not returned from accessor for xxxx, 5, mapParams  4
ERROR ErrorManager: 1409780823108: A General Exception Occurred 1
```

Comment: Please provide sample output of the log file, including some lines that are errors, and some that aren't.

Comment: @lxg: Thanks for your valuable time for reading my queries and provide your necessary information now. Thanks once again

Comment: Which information indicates the type of error? (You said you want to group it by error types.) Is it the xxxService/yyyService column?

Comment: I've formatted your sample output a bit (edit pending). But I'm not sure, is this all from one file? So, i.e. are there log files where the line has a date and others which start directly with “ERROR”?

Comment: Thanks for formatting lxg. Date will be available at first and all the information are from single log files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really write a full script, because I'm not completely clear what you want, but here's a strategy.

1. grep the file for the string 'ERROR' (Looks like you've already done this).
2. Use 'cut -d ' ' -f4 to extract the 4th space delimited field (yyyService).
3. Pipe the output into sort, then uniq -c to get the counts.
4. Pipe the result of this into 'mail'

So, you'll end up with something like this:

```
grep ERROR /shipmentService/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/logs/catalina.out | cut -d ' ' -f4 | sort | uniq -c | mail -s "This is the subject" mail@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this script. How do you I pull for last 30 minutes logs.

Comment: That part I'm not too sure on - maybe you could preprocess the file, and extract timestamps and fetch everything after '30 mins ago'. Then pipe that file into my code above?